# Using ListAdapter to show the ContactName and Number in listview using simple_list_item_2 , How to extract only Number in the onItemClick()?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Using the following class I want to select the contact from list which has Contact Name and Number.

```
public class MakeCallView extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    Button callButtn;
    EditText number2call;
    private ListView lv1 = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.makeacall);

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        callButtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CallBtn);
        number2call = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2Call);
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listContact);

        ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,


            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, new String[] {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });

        lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        callButtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3) {

        try {

            Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            View v = adapter.getFocusedChild();
            // TwoLineListItem row = (TwoLineListItem)
            // adapter.getAdapter().getView(pos, arg1,
            // (ViewGroup)adapter.getParent());
            // String a = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            // number2call.setText( c.g);
            Log.v("GPS", "arg3    : " + c.getColumnCount());
            Log.v("GPS", "arg3    : " + c.getColumnNames());
            Log.v("GPS", "arg3    : " + c.toString());
            Log.v("GPS", "arg3    : " + c.getShort(1));

            Log.v("GPS", "arg3    : " + c.getColumnIndex("text2"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.v("GPS", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        // number2call.setText(((TextView)arg1).getText().toString());

        // Handle list2 click even

    }

}
```

From the above code, in the **onItemClick()**, the selected contact number should be retrieved which I am not able to get. Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your OnItemClickListener

```
TextView txtNumber = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)
String str = txtNumber.getText()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       This will give you back the Number of selected contact
```

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {

            try {

                String x = ((TwoLineListItem) arg1).getText2().getText()
                            .toString();
                    number2call.setText(x);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v("GPS", e.getMessage(), e);
            }


    }
```